# Postgresql: ERROR: column "mayvar" does not exist whereas myvar is a variable

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to create a function in plsql to find 5 users within 1 mile range from a user passed as argument to the function.

This is my code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunction (integer) RETURNS integer as $$
    DECLARE
    myvar integer := $1;
    mylon double precision; 
    mylat double precision; 
    lon1 float; 
    lon2 float; 
    lat1 float; 
    lat2 float;
    BEGIN
    raise notice 'help = %', $1; --just for testing
    raise notice 'myvar = %', myvar; --again for testing
    select cr.last_known_longitude, cr.last_known_latitude into mylon, mylat from current_reg as cr where userid = myvar;
    lon1 = mylon - 1 / abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
    lon2 = mylon + 1/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
    lat1 = mylat - (1/69);
    lat2 = mylat + (1/69);
    create view myview as
            select destination.userid, 3956*2*asin(sqrt(power(sin((origin.last_known_latitude-destination.last_known_latitude)*pi()/180 / 2), 2) + cos(origin.last_known_latitude* pi()/180) * cos(destination.last_known_latitude* pi()/180) * power(sin((origin.last_known_longitude-destination.last_known_longitude) * pi()/180 /2), 2))) as distance
            from current_reg destination, current_reg origin
            where origin.userid = myvar
            and destination.last_known_longitude between lon1 and lon2
            and destination.last_known_latitude between lat1 and lat2
            having distance < 1 order by distance limit 5;
    return 0;
    END; 
    $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
    Select testfunction(7);
```

where current_reg is a table with userid, last_known_latitude, last_known_longitude as columns. The argument passed as integer to the function is the userid of the user from whose location(latitude and longitude) I wish to find users in a mile range.

I get the following error:

```
NOTICE:  help = 7
NOTICE:  myvar = 7

ERROR:  column "myvar" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ination, current_reg origin where origin.userid = myvar and de...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  create view myview as select destination.userid, 3956*2*asin(sqrt(power(sin((origin.last_known_latitude-destination.last_known_latitude)*pi()/180 / 2), 2) + cos(origin.last_known_latitude* pi()/180) * cos(destination.last_known_latitude* pi()/180) * power(sin((origin.last_known_longitude-destination.last_known_longitude) * pi()/180 /2), 2))) as distance from current_reg destination, current_reg origin where origin.userid = myvar and destination.last_known_longitude between lon1 and lon2 and destination.last_known_latitude between lat1 and lat2 having distance < 1 order by distance limit 5
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function testfunction(integer) line 19 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "myvar" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Context: PL/pgSQL function testfunction(integer) line 19 at SQL statement
```

Since "myvar" is a variable, why is it expecting it to be a column?

After help from @a_horse_with_no_name, this the modified code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunction (p_userid integer) 
    RETURNS table (userid integer, distance float) 
    AS 
    $$
    DECLARE
    mylon double precision; 
    mylat double precision; 
    lon1 float; 
    lon2 float; 
    lat1 float; 
    lat2 float;
    BEGIN
    raise notice 'help = %', p_userid; --just for testing

    select cr.last_known_longitude, cr.last_known_latitude 
    into mylon, mylat 
    from current_reg as cr 
    where cr.userid = p_userid;

    lon1 = mylon - 1 / abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
    lon2 = mylon + 1/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
    lat1 = mylat - (1/69);
    lat2 = mylat + (1/69);

    return query 
       select destination.userid, 
       3956*2*asin(sqrt(power(sin((origin.last_known_latitude-destination.last_known_latitude)*pi()/180 / 2), 2) + cos(origin.last_known_latitude* pi()/180) * cos(destination.last_known_latitude* pi()/180) * power(sin((origin.last_known_longitude-destination.last_known_longitude) * pi()/180 /2), 2)))
       as distance 
       from current_reg as destination JOIN current_reg as origin 
       where origin.userid = p_userid
       and destination.last_known_longitude between lon1 and lon2 
       and destination.last_known_latitude between lat1 and lat2 
       having distance < 1 
       order by distance limit 5;

    END; 
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    Select userid from testfunction(4);
```

I now get the following error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
LINE 29:     where origin.userid = p_userid
             ^

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Even after using some other name, it gives the a same result.

Comment: Ah, once I scroll over to the far right of your code (no line breaks - why?) then it's obvious: you can't use a variable in a DDL statement like that. What are you trying to achieve with that? If you just want to select the data, why are you using a `CREATE VIEW` statement at all?

Comment: Two things:
1. it gives the same error for "select cr.last_known_longitude, cr.last_known_latitude into mylon, mylat from current_reg as cr where userid = myvar;" which is a DML. Why?
And
2. I actually want to return 5 userids of users nearby. I tried using
        RETURNS setof integer
but then i was unable to return since return couldn't take parameters when a function returns setof. So instead I tried creating a view of the userid and distance which I will then manipulate using JPA.

Comment: The error you added indicates the `create view` as the source of the error, not your first select.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yeah a mistake on my part. That worked! But could you please help me in how to return 5 userids? So that way I will not have to use view anymore.

Comment: `from current_reg as destination JOIN current_reg as origin  where origin.userid = p_userid` please read the manual. The syntax for joining tables is explained there.

Comment: If you install the PostGIS extension you can use the st_distance function to do exactly what you're trying to do without having to write your own function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the result of the query, you need to use `return query` in PL/pgSQL. You can't use a variable in a DDL statement like that. Creating a view for **each and every** invocation of the function is a really bad idea. And what's more: your function would fail when invoked for the second time, because the view already exists.

From what you have written, I *think* you want something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunction (p_userid integer) 
  RETURNS table (userid integer, distance float) 
AS 
$$
DECLARE
  mylon double precision; 
  mylat double precision; 
  lon1 float; 
  lon2 float; 
  lat1 float; 
  lat2 float;
BEGIN
  raise notice 'help = %', p_userid; --just for testing

  select cr.last_known_longitude, cr.last_known_latitude 
      into mylon, mylat 
  from current_reg as cr 
  where userid = p_userid;

  lon1 = mylon - 1 / abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
  lon2 = mylon + 1/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69);
  lat1 = mylat - (1/69);
  lat2 = mylat + (1/69);

  return query 
    select destination.userid, 
           3956*2*asin(sqrt(power(sin((origin.last_known_latitude-destination.last_known_latitude)*pi()/180 / 2), 2) + cos(origin.last_known_latitude* pi()/180) * cos(destination.last_known_latitude* pi()/180) * power(sin((origin.last_known_longitude-destination.last_known_longitude) * pi()/180 /2), 2))) as distance 
    from current_reg destination, 
         current_reg origin 
    where origin.userid = p_userid
      and destination.last_known_longitude between lon1 and lon2 
      and destination.last_known_latitude between lat1 and lat2 
    having distance < 1 
    order by distance limit 5;

END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

1. You want to return the result of the query, so your function should be declared as `returns table`.
2. You can give the parameter a name, no need to obfuscate your code by duplicating it.
3. To return the result of a query in PL/pgSQL you need `return query`.

To get the result of that function use:

```
select *
from testfunction(1);
```

Note the function is in the `FROM` clause, not in the `SELECT` list!

Things that still look suspicious:

1. you are not joining the two tables `from current_reg destination, current_reg origin` creates a **cross join** between the two. Another good example why using an explicit `JOIN` is better than the old implicit joins in the where clause
2. You are using `having` but not using any aggregates